# Системные требования к современному Xcode

Tags: xcode

Добрый день.
Хочу купить б/у мак для обучения и работы в Xcode. Бюджет крайне мал. Просьба подсказать каких системных требований будет достаточно для работы с Xcode.
Благодарю.

Comment: Я что-то не смог найти требований конкретно под Xcode, но наверное можно ориентироваться по требованиям для последей версии OS X: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5842 . Самый бюджетный вариант - это Mac Mini. Вы под iOS собираетесь разрабатывать? Тогда еще нужен будет iPhone и подписка на iOS Developer Program ($99 в год).

Comment: Ориентируюсь на мобильную разработку.

Comment: На первых парах аккаунт разработчика ($99) можно не покупать, работать с симулятором. Возможностей, конечно, чуть меньше, но если по деньгам не выходит - это не критично.

Answer (score 1):

iMac в нашем офисе (модель early 2011): 4Gb оперативки, Intel Core i5. Производительность конечно не супер, но работать можно. Когда вставили туда SSD диски стало гораздо приятнее. Вполне подойдет **Mac Mini или MacBook Pro 2011** года не самой топовой конфигурации. 
Точно **НЕ подойдет Core 2 Duo** и **меньше 4Gb памяти**.

Comment: Извиняюсь за дотошность.
А такой вариант на первое время потянет?
http://kiev.ko.slando.ua/obyavlenie/prodam-macbook-pro-2007-ID8cXpf.html#9d3918385b

Comment: Как я и написал выше, я бы рекомендовал Core 2 Duo, у меня был такой, на нем жутко тормозил даже xCode 4, а текуший 5. С 1 февраля в аппстор нельзя будет загружать приложения, собранные в xCode ниже 5й версии, поэтому посмотрите хотя бы на Intel Core i3 или i5